# compress image before saving without changing ratio in dotnet core

Tags: compression, image-compression

in my code I take image as input.
My user does not know much about technology , so they expect to give any image size they want , but I have limitations and I can't save larger images in my disc, so I want to compress images before saving them in my disc .
I appreciate helping me with this compression.

Comment: I got a library : Magick.NET it can compress files and it has a property called Quality. but I want to resize my file to a certain size as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how i solved my problem using Magick.NET library :
i used the quality property to reduce the size and i did it in a loop , while the image size reaches my goal size :

```
 MagickImage magickImge = new MagickImage(image);
                int quality = magickImge.Quality;
                long length = image.Length;
                while (length > fileSizeInByte)
                {
                    if (quality <= 6)
                    {
                        return Error;

                    }

                    quality = quality - ((quality * 15) / 100);

                    MagickImage lowQualityImage = new MagickImage(image);
                    lowQualityImage.Quality = quality;
                    byte[] newImageBytes = lowQualityImage.ToByteArray();

                    if (newImageBytes.Length <= fileSizeInByte)
                    {
                        magickImge.Quality = quality;
                        length = newImageBytes.Length;
                    }

                }
```

i see that if the quality goes below 6 my pic will be illegible

Comment: Please edit your question if you want to add more context to it. Please remove the answer as it is not an answer